# jQuery('#myModal:visible').length === 0 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the equivalent of `jQuery('#myModal:visible').length === 0`  in pure JS ?

I have used the code below, but its returns a **TypeError** that

> TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle is not an object.

---

```
const element = document.querySelector("#myModal");
return window.getComputedStyle(element).display === 'none';
```

## update

This code only works if there is not any `#myModal` is the `DOM` at all.

```js
const element = document.querySelector("#myModal");
return element === null;
```

## Update

I have a modal, but it is `display` property is `none` by default.

Comment: `document.querySelector("#myModal") === null`

Comment: I would start debugging. Put a breakpoint on the `return` line and check the value of `element`.

Comment: BTW, in jQuery you could simplify that code with `jQuery('#myModal').is(':visible')`, but that's beside the point :).

Comment: Please ask a new question (as you've received several answers which answered your original question). In this new question, please include a [mcve], providing the HTML you are running this JavaScript against.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `querySelector` you can simply use `getElementById`.

```js
const isModalVisible = (id) => {
  const modal = document.getElementById(id);
  return modal !== null && window.getComputedStyle(modal).display === "none";
}
```

```css
#myModal {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<button onclick="alert(isModalVisible('myModal')) 
">Is Modal Hidden?</button>
```

The `querySelector` is not supported by all IE browsers

[Can I use querySelector?](https://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector)

Comment: I saw you updated your answer! Well in your case, the problem can be easily solved with plain old Javascript. Why not go with full compatibiity :))

Comment: My bad! The style property doesn't get the computed styles.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're assuming the element gets found.

`querySelector` returns a reference to an HTML object OR `null` if the query didn't match an element.

With this in mind, you have to imagine your second line is this:

```
return window.getComputedStyle(null).display === 'none';
```

And it's now obvious why you're getting an error; you can't get the computed style of `null`.

Fix:

```
const element = document.querySelector("#myModal");
if (element)
    return window.getComputedStyle(element).display === 'none';
```

Comment: Does not work. I have a modal, but its `display` property is `none`.

Comment: That was not your question. I have answered the question you asked, and the code is sound.